# How to list all the variable of certain type in python?

Tags: python

When I type `dir()` in python , it can show all the variables visible, such as:

```
>>> dir()
['ACCT', 'ACEV', 'ALLOW_THREADS', 'ANNOTE_FONT', 'Annotation', 'AnnoteFinder', 'Arrow', 'Artist', 'AutoLocator', 'Axes', 'BS_KM', 'BUFSIZE', 'Button', 'CF_KM']
```

Now I want a function that can list all the variables of certain type, for example '`str`', by :

```
>>list_all_variable_of_type(str)
```

It will return a list of the variable whose type is 'str' .

How to write the `'list_all_variable_of_type()`' function ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dir` just shows the names. You'll need `globals()` to access the actual variables. So probably:

```
[name for name, value in globals().items() if isinstance(value, basestring)]
```

(Note that if you're relying on this to access an unknown set of variables, you're probably doing it wrong; you should store your data in an overall data structure like a dict.)